# JScrollPane - thumbnail images won't scroll horizontally

Tags: css, jquery-jscrollpane

I have unordered list of thumbnail images to display horizontally across bottom of page. I want a few of the images to be visible while the others are scrolled horizontally in/out upon scrollbar use.

However I can't get my images to line up in one continuous line - they break up at the 100% width mark.

This may be an issue with my css rather than with jscrollpane.

Demonstration here: http://www.air.desensdesigns.com/temp.html

CSS:

```
 #thumbnails{
position:fixed;
top:86%;
left:0px;
height:125px;
width:100%;
background:rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}

#thumbnails ul{
position:relative;
top:5px;
}

#thumbnails li{
list-style:none;
float:left;
margin:5px;
padding:0px;
height:100px;
width:133px;
border:2px solid #333;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $thumbnails.jScrollPane({});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a width to ul:

```
#thumbnails ul {
    position: relative;
    top: 5px;
    width: 5000px;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Try add this:

```
.jspHorizontalBar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 52px;
    background: red;
}
```

My Test:

[image]

Comment: I have made changes, however no desired result was achieved.

Comment: I was still adding a % rather than a fixed px width. Thanks a million!